# AMP on a separate route or the same route

Tags: google-amp, accelerated-mobile-page

We are currently hosting our AMP pages on `/restaurant/:id/amp` but our main pages `/restaurants/:id` have pretty much behavior. So in short we can choose to discontinue `/amp`route and keep it hosted on the main route. I couldn't find Google's take on it, possible advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this documentation [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery).

What if I only have one page?
If you only have one page, and that page is an AMP page, you must still add the canonical link to it, which will then simply point to itself:

> link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html"